# How to define custom configuration to filter ScalaTest tests in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I already know (and have working) the ability to

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html
- http://code.hootsuite.com/tagged-tests-with-sbt/
- http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scalatest-mark-tests-tags-to-include-exclude-sbt

for `project/Build.scala` style sbt projects.

However, I do not know how (or if it is possible) to do this in a simple `build.sbt` project: the problem is when `configs` is called on the `Project`.

**If it is possible to apply `Tag` filters to scalatest, how does one do it in a `build.sbt`?**

Note: I don't want the filter in `Test`, I want it in a custom `Configuration`. The workaround is to use `test-only * -- -l SlowTest` (which is kinda clunky).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one can now define a `root` in a `build.sbt`, so the above sytax is allowed

e.g.

```
lazy val root = project in file(".") settings (
          ...
) configs ( MY CONFIG GOES HERE)
```